# Decrease border width of SF Symbol

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

Decrease border width of the image, Its SF Symbol, I tried different ways but its not working

```
struct CheckboxView: View {
    var isSelected: Bool
    var size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: isSelected ? "rectangle.inset.filled" : "rectangle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}

struct CheckboxView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CheckboxView(isSelected: false)
    }
}
```

Currently [image]

To this
[image]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want to decrease it, I have added this images

Comment: Wouldn´t a Roundedrectangle work too? I think you can use them without filling and adjust their border width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is

```
Image(systemName: isSelected ? "rectangle.inset.filled" : "rectangle")
    .resizable()
    .fontWeight(.light) // <--
```

or even

```
Image(systemName: isSelected ? "rectangle.inset.filled" : "rectangle")
    .resizable()
    .fontWeight(.ultraLight) // <--
```

thin enough?